# What to pass as a SYS_REFCURSOR argument

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, arguments

Here I have a stored procedure in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE StP_COMPS
IS
 CV_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
 OPEN CV_1  FOR SELECT * FROM COMPUTERS;
END;
```

When I execute the procedure like EXEC SP_COMPS I get no error, the SQL Developer just shows "ananymous block completed". Then I change the procedure to a

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_COMPS
      (cv_1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
 OPEN CV_1  FOR SELECT * FROM COMPUTERS;
END;
```

and when I execute I get error stating that the number of type of the arguments are wrong. I'm very curious what I could send as an argument to the procedure if it's just an output parameter. I want to get the result set of the query run inside the procedure. What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. When I try to run the procedure by right clicking the procedure and selecting Run I get:

```
 DECLARE
  CV_2 sys_refcursor;
 BEGIN

 SP_COMPS(
    CV_2 => CV_2
    );

 :CV_2 := CV_2; -- <--Can't understand this part
 END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable, you should execute the procedure like:

```
DECLARE
  CV_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  SP_COMPS(CV_1);
  --use cv_1
END;
```

**UPDATE**(after OP update): That's a simple template for testing. As explained here: [Easiest method to test an Oracle Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952663/easiest-method-to-test-an-oracle-stored-procedure), just run that code, and select ref_cursor as type of cv2 variable.