# Show the results of a SYS_REFCURSOR from Oracle stored procedure, using Toad (9.0.1.8) with fully qualified schema name

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, toad

Wow.  I'm a Sql Server guy, trying to learn Oracle.
No horse in the race, just using the db that my job requires.

How do I see the results of a simple OUT SYS_REFCURSOR.
(Using TOAD 9.0.1.8)
(Oracle Environment = 10g)

Code below.  Please know that using fully qualified names (schema + object_name) is the "norm" around here.  (And please know I only kinda know what I'm talking about when it comes to Oracle)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SYS.PROC_GET_MY_COOL_TABLES (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_recordset FOR


SELECT 
      TABLE_NAME 
    , TABLE_TYPE 
from 
    SYS.USER_CATALOG 
where 
    TABLE_TYPE = 'TABLE' and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%$%'
;


END PROC_GET_MY_COOL_TABLES;


/



variable myVarForARefCur refcursor;
exec SYS.PROC_GET_MY_COOL_TABLES( :myVarForARefCur );
print myVarForARefCur;


/
```

Comment: You don't need the final `/` - it will just recreate the procedure. And you really shouldn't create anything in the `SYS` schema, ever. The `variable/exec/print` is exactly what I'd do in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, but I don't know if Toad supports it, which I realise isn't very helpful. What happens when you try?

Comment: I would normally not create anything in SYS.  I just needed a demo.  (So I didn't have to post the full DDL.)

Comment: [This](http://heather.koyuk.net/refractions/?p=343) suggests you can run an anonymous PL/SQL block - which is all the `exec` is really - as a program; no idea if it's relevant to your version of Toad though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952663/easiest-method-to-test-an-oracle-stored-procedure

I up voted Brian's answer!

Thank YOU!