# changing how oracle output results

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql, toad

please read carefully and if you do not understand what I am saying please let me know.

Below are the tables names and the columns in those tables

**table:** SYSTEM_USER_SKILL

```
    user_id
    skill_id
    user_abilities
```

**table:** SYSTEM_ADMIN_SKILL

```
skill_id
skill_name
```

**table:** SYSTEM_USER

```
user_id
user_full_name
```

I want to write a dynmanic sql or a pl/sql which will display the user_full_name and user_ability.

but I want it to display like this:

[image]

p.s. where you see the "Y" and "N" those are results from user_abilities

I dont know how to do this all i know is that it can be done with dynamic sql or pl/sql

Comment: Display where? Do you already have the query to get the values and combinations? You want the grid of output, or the exact headings like that (rotation would have to be left to you...)? Do you have a fixed number of skills, or are you trying to find a way to do a pivot with a dynamic number of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the data in tabular form can be done with a `pivot`, as long as you're on Oracle 11gR2:

```
select * from (
  select su.user_full_name, sas.skill_name, sus.user_abilities
  from system_user su
  cross join system_admin_skill sas
  left join system_user_skill sus on sus.user_id = su.user_id
    and sus.skill_id = sas.skill_id
) pivot (max(user_abilities) as able for (skill_name)
    in ('php' as php, 'java' as java, 'pl/sql / sql' as plsql_sql,
      'Oracle apex' as oracle_apex));

USER_FULL_NAME       PHP_ABLE JAVA_ABLE PLSQL_SQL_ABLE ORACLE_APEX_ABLE
-------------------- -------- --------- -------------- ----------------
Sarah woods          N        N         Y              Y                
John brown           N        Y         Y              Y                
Johnny paterson      Y        Y         Y              Y                
Amy brown            N        N         Y              N
```

but you need to list each skill explicitly in the `in` clause. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61698/1).

In SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you could get the headings you want with something like:

```
column user_full_name heading "Name"
column php_able format a15 heading "php"
column java_able format a15 heading "java"
column plsql_sql_able format a15 heading "pl/sql / sql"
column oracle_apex_able format a15 heading "Oracle apex"

select ...

Name                 php             java            pl/sql / sql    Oracle apex   
-------------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
Sarah woods          N               N               Y               Y               
John brown           N               Y               Y               Y               
Johnny paterson      Y               Y               Y               Y               
Amy brown            N               N               Y               N
```

... but I have no idea if Toad has anything similar.

---

The non-pivot equivalent of this, which you would have had to use in older versions, would be something like:

```
select su.user_id, su.user_full_name,
  max(case when sas.skill_id = 1 then sus.user_abilities end) as php,
  max(case when sas.skill_id = 2 then sus.user_abilities end) as java,
  max(case when sas.skill_id = 3 then sus.user_abilities end) as plsql_sql,
  max(case when sas.skill_id = 4 then sus.user_abilities end) as oracle_apex
from system_user su
cross join system_admin_skill sas
left join system_user_skill sus on sus.user_id = su.user_id
  and sus.skill_id = sas.skill_id
group by su.user_id, su.user_full_name;
```

This still has all the skills hard-coded in. To allow for additional skills without having to modify the query you'd need to build it dynamically, as shown in earlier answers linked to in comments. In this specific case you could do something like:

```
create or replace function get_skill_matrix return sys_refcursor as
  query varchar2(32767);
  rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  query := 'select su.user_id, su.user_full_name';
  for tmp in (select skill_id, skill_name from system_admin_skill
      order by skill_id)
  loop
    query := query || ', max(case when sas.skill_id = ' || tmp.skill_id
      || ' then sus.user_abilities end) as "'
      || substr(tmp.skill_name, 1, 30) || '"';
  end loop;
  query := query || ' from system_user su';
  query := query || ' cross join system_admin_skill sas';
  query := query || ' left join system_user_skill sus on sus.user_id = su.user_id';
  query := query || ' and sus.skill_id = sas.skill_id';
  query := query || ' group by su.user_id, su.user_full_name';

  open rc for query;

  return rc;
end;
/
```

The `query` string used for the dynamic SQL is just built up to look exactly the same as the static version, but with each `skill_id`-specific clause generated in a loop from the base `system_admin_skill` table.

When you call this function you get a cursor back. You haven't really said how or where you're using the results. You can treat it as a result set in a Java program, for example, by executing the function and then calling `getCursor()` on the statement object. In SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you can use the `variable` and `print` commands to display it:

```
var rc refcursor;
exec :rc := get_skill_matrix;
print rc
```

In SQL Developer that gives:

```
anonymous block completed
RC
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_ID                                 USER_FULL_NAME       java php pl/sql / sql Oracle apex 
--------------------------------------- -------------------- ---- --- ------------ ----------- 
3                                       Amy brown            N    N   Y            N           
4                                       Sarah woods          N    N   Y            Y           
2                                       Johnny paterson      Y    Y   Y            Y           
1                                       John brown           Y    N   Y            Y
```

Or in SQL*Plus, where you can do `column user_id noprint` to hide the ID (which I've included in case two people have the same name!):

```
Name                 j p p O
-------------------- - - - -
Amy brown            N N Y N
Sarah woods          N N Y Y
Johnny paterson      Y Y Y Y
John brown           Y N Y Y
```

In Toad I *think* you can do this, which is all the `exec` is doing anyway:

begin
    :rc := get_skill_matrix;
  end;

... and it'll prompt you for the bind type for `:rc`; if you pick 'ref cursor' it'll show the results in the data grid. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953831/266304).

---

OK, same thing but without a function (but still PL/SQL), and including the skill ID in the column alias before truncating to make it unique:

```
var rc refcursor

declare
  query varchar2(32767);
begin
  query := 'select su.user_id, su.user_full_name as "Name"';
  for tmp in (select skill_id, skill_name from system_admin_skill
      order by skill_id) loop
    query := query || ', max(case when sas.skill_id = ' || tmp.skill_id
      || ' then sus.user_abilities end) as "'
      || substr(tmp.skill_id || ' ' || tmp.skill_name, 1, 30) || '"';
  end loop;
  query := query || ' from system_user su';
  query := query || ' cross join system_admin_skill sas';
  query := query || ' left join system_user_skill sus on sus.user_id = su.user_id';
  query := query || ' and sus.skill_id = sas.skill_id';
  query := query || ' group by su.user_id, su.user_full_name';

  open :rc for query;
end;
/

print rc
```

Which gives:

```
RC
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_ID        Name                 1 java 2 php 3 pl/sql / sql 4 Oracle apex 
-------------- -------------------- ------ ----- -------------- ------------- 
3              Amy brown            N      N     Y              N             
4              Sarah woods          N      N     Y              Y             
2              Johnny paterson      Y      Y     Y              Y             
1              John brown           Y      N     Y              Y
```

Comment: little addition: you can easily deal with dynamic columns amount if you do pivot into XML and then use it e.g. in Excel

Comment: @Simon - not sure if dynamic columns are needed yet, though looks like they probably will be. I might have to try that though; still, depends how the output is going to be used or further manipulated.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks alot. I have never heard of Pivot and i have had this opportunity to learn it now. Thanks again

Comment: I have one question, because the skill name is more than jusy php. java, etc who will i avoid having to list them? because new skills could be added in the future and also we have over 60 skills in the `SYSTEM_ADMIN_SKILL` table

Comment: @user3057514 - not as simply. Yhat's what Simon's comment was referring to, but it depends how you're using the output. You can also build a dynamic query, [as shown herefor example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16978047/266304). It may be simpler to have a process to modufy your pivot query when new values are added, if that will not be very frequent - trade off of clarity and maintainability, I suppose.

Comment: @AlexPoole looking for the example in the like you provide. I need to change your answer to something similar to that?

Comment: @AlexPoole will it be possible for you to post a new answer please? Thats if you have sometime to spare. Thanks

Comment: @user3057514 - OK, I've added a dynamic version. Hope that makes sense. And, [here's some background on ref cursors](https://community.oracle.com/thread/888365?tstart=0).

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks again, got one noob question. In sql developer do i call the function like `var rc refcursor;
exec :rc := get_skill_matrix;
print rc` and in toad like `begin :rc := get_skill_matrix; end;`? i have both toad and sql developer

Comment: @user3057514 - in SQL Developer, `exec :rc := get_skill_matrix;` is the same as `begin :rc := get_skill_matrix; end;`, it's just shorthand (mostly), so you can use either. The difference in SQL Developer is that you declare the cursor variable with `var rc ref cursor` and display it with `print rc`; in Toad you don't have those commands, you're prompted to pick the cursor type when you run it, and it's displayed in the data grid. I think!

Comment: Have you done the `var rc refcursor`? I think you might have to run as a script, not as a statement.

Comment: @AlexPoole i keep getting `identifier is too long` and it pointing to `open rc for query;` so i did a `dmbs_output_put_line(query);` just before it and i got nothing. which means thats the query are not executing

Comment: yea, I did `begin :rc := get_skill_matrix; end;` in toad and i choose `cursor` for the type and i keeping that `identifier is too long` error

Comment: @AlexPoole sorry i got some results from the `dmbs` it just took longer to run

Comment: Oh... how big is your `system_admin_skill.skill_name` column, and what is the longest value in it? If it's more than 30 characters you'll need to truncate it in the loop, like `|| substr(tmp.skill_name, 1, 30) ||`, though even that seems rather long.

Comment: @AlexPoole the result i got was not database results just alot of select statements over and over

Comment: @user3057514 - from `dbms_output`? That's what you'd expect. (Maybe not over and over, but if you ran it initially without `set serveroutput on` then those outputs would have been cached and you'd see them all in one go the first time you ran it with than turned on). If you run it now with `dbms_output` you should see a single query with lots of `max` expressions; if you add the `substr` and go back to opening the cursor you should see the results?

Comment: @AlexPoole this is not out of the question is too much. I have apply your solution to another project. but for the orginal project i needed this for i need to do it in pl/sql and save it in csv format.

Comment: So in the dynamic string, concatenate the `max` values with a `||'',''||' between each one (instead of the plain comma that's there now). If you can't make that work then start a new question, this is getting a bit ridiculous... *8-)

Comment: Yes i will start a new one. Thanks alot for your time. I really appreciate it